# Клик по одному из всех возможных потомков

Tags: javascript

Хочу реализовать на нативном `javascript` функцию для закрывания дропдауна по клику вне его со следующей идеей: скрывать родителя по клику не на этого родителя и не на его потомков. Проблема: не понимаю, как перебрать всех потомков, т.к. только дочерние элементы (childNodes) не подходят.

Примерный код в HTML:

```
<section class="dropdown">
    <div class="button">
        <span>&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4</li>
            <li>Menu 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Мои догадки по поводу JS:

```
var button = document.querySelector('.dropdown .button');
var menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown .menu');
var menuChildren = menu.getElementsByTagName('*');
// button.onclick = function() {
//   if (menu.style.display == 'none') {
//     menu.style.display = 'block';
//   } else {
//     menu.style.display = 'none';
//   };
// }
for (var i=0; i<menuChildren.length; i++) {
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target != menu || e.target != menuChildren[i]) {
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    };
  };
};
```

P.S. закомментированный код - закрытие по нажатию на крестик. можно ли его переписать в более ёмком виде? через оператор `?` например?

Comment: рекурсивно, детей детей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете пробегать всех родителей примерно так:

```
window.onclick=function(e){
    var node=e.target;
    while(node.parentNode) {
       if(node== menu){
           //Мы щелкнули по меню или его потомку
           return;
       }
       node = node.parentNode;
    }
    //Мы щелкнули мимо меню
}
```

Насчет тернарного оператора, в данном случае это выглядит так:

```
menu.style.display = (menu.style.display == 'none')?'block':'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях я останавливаю всплытие события по клику на меню, а по клику на тело документа - просто скрываю это меню

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.dropdown .button');
var menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown .menu');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.onclick = close;
button.onclick = close;
menu.onclick = stopPropagation;
function close(e){
  menu.style.display = 'none';
}
function stopPropagation(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="dropdown">
    <div class="button">
      <span>&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  Нажми сюда - это body
</body>
```